# How to return a function result instead of doclist in the Solr collapsing/grouping feature?

Tags: solr

I have the following solr fields in schema.xml:

- id (string)
- name (string)
- category(string)
- latitude (double)
- longitude(double)

Is it possible to make a query that groups by category and returns the average of latitude and longitude instead of the doclist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group by category you may want use [Solr facet fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) you can combine it with [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent)

Comment: I combined facet with stats without success. I had to make my own SearchComponent.